# Optimizar consulta

Tags: mysql

La consulta verifica los movimientos de stock y genera una grilla para poder ser mostrada al cliente.
Resulta que cada cambio que se realiza a cada producto, se registra en una tabla que se llama movimiento de productos la cual es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE `movimientostock` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `fechademovimiento` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `idproducto` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `razondemovimiento` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `datonuevo` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `nombreanterior` TEXT NULL,
    `nombrenuevo` TEXT NULL,
    `datoanterior` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `datoextra` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `empleado` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `computadoraid` TEXT NULL,
    `host` TEXT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id`),
    INDEX `razondemovimiento` (`razondemovimiento`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=109096
;
```

Ahora bien, cuando se modifica el nombre de un producto se ingresa el id del producto "IDPRODUCTO", con la razón de movimiento "CAMBIO DE NOMBRE" y se registra el nombre de este anterior y el nuevo. Así como eso también se registra "cambio de precio", cambio de "código de barras" entre muchas otras. Cada cambio que se realiza se ingresa el dato anterior y el dato nuevo, puede ser cadena o también un decimal. También se registra el usuario y desde que maquina se realiza la modificación. De esta manera guardo toda la informacion necesaria de manera mas compacta posible, el problema es al generar la tabla de movimientos. Yo he realizado una consulta con multiples WHEN para poder formar una tabla a mostrar sencilla pero para hacerlo hay que hacer una consulta bastante compleja, aqui esta el problema, recorre demasiados registros para generar la consulta, aqui muestro el SQL

```
Select movimientostock.id AS Id, movimientostock.fechademovimiento As 'Fecha de Movimiento', 
(CASE WHEN movimientostock.razondemovimiento IN ('CAMBIO DE PRODUCTO A VENTA FRACCIONARIA', 'VENTA', 'CAMBIO DE CODIGO DE BARRAS', 'CAMBIO DE PROVEEDOR', 'CAMBIO DE CATEGORÍA', 'CAMBIO DE NOMBRE', 'ENTRADA DE STOCK', 'SALIDA DE STOCK', 'CAMBIO DE TIPO DE PRODUCTO', 'ENTRADA DE BULTO CERRADO', 'SALIDA DE BULTO CERRADO', 'SALIDA DE BULTO ABIERTO', 'ENTRADA DE BULTO ABIERTO', 'CAMBIO DE STOCK MINIMO', 'BAJA DE PRODUCTO', 'RESTAURACIÓN DE PRODUCTO', 'BAJA DE PRODUCTO', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO FRACCIONARIO', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO COSTO', 'CAMBIO DE GANANCIA', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO DE LISTA', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO ESPECIAL DE LISTA', 'INGRESO DE PRECIO DE LISTA', 'INGRESO DE PRECIO ESPECIAL DE LISTA') THEN IFNULL((SELECT productos.nombre FROM productos WHERE productos.id = movimientostock.idproducto),'') 
    WHEN movimientostock.razondemovimiento IN ('CAMBIO DE UNIDAD MEDIDA', 'CAMBIO DE UNIDAD ABREVIADO', 'CAMBIO DE NOMBRE DE TIPO', 'CAMBIO DE CANTIDAD DE TIPO', 'ELIMINA TIPO DE PRODUCTO', 'AGREGAR TIPO DE PRODUCTO') THEN IFNULL((SELECT tipodeproducto.nombre FROM tipodeproducto WHERE tipodeproducto.id = movimientostock.idproducto),'')
       "ELSE '' END) AS 'Nombre',
    movimientostock.razondemovimiento AS 'Tipo de Movimiento',
    (CASE WHEN movimientostock.razondemovimiento IN ('CAMBIO DE PRODUCTO A VENTA ESPECIAL' ,'CAMBIO DE CODIGO DE BARRAS', 'CAMBIO DE PROVEEDOR', 'CAMBIO DE CATEGORÍA', 'CAMBIO DE NOMBRE', 'ALTA DE PRODUCTO', 'BAJA DE PRODUCTO', 'AGREGAR TIPO DE PRODUCTO', 'CAMBIO DE UNIDAD MEDIDA', 'CAMBIO DE UNIDAD ABREVIADO', 'CAMBIO DE NOMBRE DE TIPO') THEN movimientostock.nombrenuevo 
   WHEN movimientostock.razondemovimiento IN ('INGRESO DE PRECIO DE LISTA', 'INGRESO DE PRECIO ESPECIAL DE LISTA', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO FRACCIONARIO', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO COSTO', 'CAMBIO DE GANANCIA', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO DE LISTA', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO ESPECIAL DE LISTA', 'INGRESO DE PRECIO DE LISTA', 'INGRESO DE PRECIO ESPECIAL DE LISTA') THEN pasaradinero(movimientostock.datonuevo)" & vbCrLf & _
WHEN movimientostock.razondemovimiento IN ('ENTRADA DE STOCK', 'SALIDA DE STOCK', 'CAMBIO DE CANTIDAD DE TIPO', 'RESTAURACIÓN DE PRODUCTO', 'CAMBIO DE STOCK MINIMO', 'ENTRADA DE BULTO ABIERTO', 'SALIDA DE BULTO ABIERTO', 'SALIDA DE BULTO CERRADO', 'ENTRADA DE BULTO CERRADO') THEN IFNULL(movimientostock.datonuevo,0)
ELSE ''  END) AS 'Dato Nuevo',
(CASE WHEN movimientostock.razondemovimiento IN ('CAMBIO DE PRODUCTO A VENTA ESPECIAL' ,'CAMBIO DE CODIGO DE BARRAS', 'CAMBIO DE PROVEEDOR', 'CAMBIO DE CATEGORÍA', 'CAMBIO DE NOMBRE', 'ALTA DE PRODUCTO', 'BAJA DE PRODUCTO', 'AGREGAR TIPO DE PRODUCTO', 'CAMBIO DE UNIDAD MEDIDA', 'CAMBIO DE UNIDAD ABREVIADO', 'CAMBIO DE NOMBRE DE TIPO')  THEN movimientostock.nombreanterior WHEN movimientostock.razondemovimiento IN ('INGRESO DE PRECIO DE LISTA', 'INGRESO DE PRECIO ESPECIAL DE LISTA', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO FRACCIONARIO', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO COSTO', 'CAMBIO DE GANANCIA', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO DE LISTA', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO ESPECIAL DE LISTA', 'INGRESO DE PRECIO DE LISTA', 'INGRESO DE PRECIO ESPECIAL DE LISTA') THEN pasaradinero(movimientostock.datoanterior)
WHEN movimientostock.razondemovimiento IN ('ENTRADA DE STOCK', 'SALIDA DE STOCK', 'CAMBIO DE CANTIDAD DE TIPO', 'RESTAURACIÓN DE PRODUCTO', 'CAMBIO DE STOCK MINIMO', 'ENTRADA DE BULTO ABIERTO', 'SALIDA DE BULTO ABIERTO', 'SALIDA DE BULTO CERRADO', 'ENTRADA DE BULTO CERRADO') THEN (IFNULL(movimientostock.datoanterior,0)) 
ELSE ''  END) AS 'Dato Anterior',
(CASE WHEN movimientostock.razondemovimiento IN ('VENTA', 'ENTRADA DE STOCK', 'SALIDA DE STOCK', 'ENTRADA DE BULTO CERRADO', 'SALIDA DE BULTO CERRADO', 'SALIDA DE BULTO ABIERTO', 'ENTRADA DE BULTO ABIERTO', 'AGREGAR TIPO DE PRODUCTO')  THEN movimientostock.datoextra ELSE ''  END) AS 'Cantidad', (CASE WHEN movimientostock.razondemovimiento IN ('AGREGAR TIPO DE PRODUCTO', 'ELIMINA TIPO DE PRODUCTO' , 'CAMBIO DE CANTIDAD DE TIPO', 'CAMBIO DE NOMBRE DE TIPO', 'CAMBIO DE UNIDAD ABREVIADO', 'CAMBIO DE UNIDAD MEDIDA') THEN 1 WHEN movimientostock.razondemovimiento IN ('INGRESO DE PRECIO ESPECIAL DE LISTA', 'INGRESO DE PRECIO DE LISTA', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO ESPECIAL DE LISTA', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO DE LISTA', 'CAMBIO DE GANANCIA', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO COSTO', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO FRACCIONARIO', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO') THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Tìpo', (IFNULL((SELECT nombre FROM empleados WHERE id = empleado),'')) AS Empleado FROM movimientostock
```

Se ve compleja, pero no lo es tanto. Por cada campo yo selecciono el tipo de dato dependiendo del tipo de movimiento. Espero si alguien tiene alguna mejor idea o existe algo que no tarde tanto para realizar este trabajo Aqui un ejemplo:

> ## Query_time: 0.037028  Lock_time: 0.000271  Rows_sent: 9  Rows_examined: 33202
>
> ## Rows_affected: 0 SET timestamp=1509458665; Select movimientostock.id AS Id, movimientostock.fechademovimiento As 'Fecha de Movimiento',
>
> (CASE WHEN movimientostock.razondemovimiento IN ('CAMBIO DE PRODUCTO A
>   VENTA FRACCIONARIA', 'VENTA', 'CAMBIO DE CODIGO DE BARRAS', 'CAMBIO DE
>   PROVEEDOR', 'CAMBIO DE CATEGORÍA', 'CAMBIO DE NOMBRE', 'ENTRADA DE
>   STOCK', 'SALIDA DE STOCK', 'CAMBIO DE TIPO DE PRODUCTO', 'ENTRADA DE
>   BULTO CERRADO', 'SALIDA DE BULTO CERRADO', 'SALIDA DE BULTO ABIERTO',
>   'ENTRADA DE BULTO ABIERTO', 'CAMBIO DE STOCK MINIMO', 'BAJA DE
>   PRODUCTO', 'RESTAURACIÓN DE PRODUCTO', 'BAJA DE PRODUCTO', 'CAMBIO DE
>   PRECIO', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO FRACCIONARIO', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO COSTO',
>   'CAMBIO DE GANANCIA', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO DE LISTA', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO
>   ESPECIAL DE LISTA', 'INGRESO DE PRECIO DE LISTA', 'INGRESO DE PRECIO
>   ESPECIAL DE LISTA') THEN IFNULL((SELECT productos.nombre FROM
>   productos WHERE productos.id = movimientostock.idproducto),'')  WHEN
>   movimientostock.razondemovimiento IN ('CAMBIO DE UNIDAD MEDIDA',
>   'CAMBIO DE UNIDAD ABREVIADO', 'CAMBIO DE NOMBRE DE TIPO', 'CAMBIO DE
>   CANTIDAD DE TIPO', 'ELIMINA TIPO DE PRODUCTO', 'AGREGAR TIPO DE
>   PRODUCTO') THEN IFNULL((SELECT tipodeproducto.nombre FROM
>   tipodeproducto WHERE tipodeproducto.id =
>   movimientostock.idproducto),'')  ELSE '' END) AS 'Nombre',
>   movimientostock.razondemovimiento AS 'Tipo de Movimiento', (CASE WHEN
>   movimientostock.razondemovimiento IN ('CAMBIO DE PRODUCTO A VENTA
>   ESPECIAL' ,'CAMBIO DE CODIGO DE BARRAS', 'CAMBIO DE PROVEEDOR',
>   'CAMBIO DE CATEGORÍA', 'CAMBIO DE NOMBRE', 'ALTA DE PRODUCTO', 'BAJA
>   DE PRODUCTO', 'AGREGAR TIPO DE PRODUCTO', 'CAMBIO DE UNIDAD MEDIDA',
>   'CAMBIO DE UNIDAD ABREVIADO', 'CAMBIO DE NOMBRE DE TIPO') THEN
>   movimientostock.nombrenuevo  WHEN movimientostock.razondemovimiento IN
>   ('INGRESO DE PRECIO DE LISTA', 'INGRESO DE PRECIO ESPECIAL DE LISTA',
>   'CAMBIO DE PRECIO', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO FRACCIONARIO', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO
>   COSTO', 'CAMBIO DE GANANCIA', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO DE LISTA', 'CAMBIO DE
>   PRECIO ESPECIAL DE LISTA', 'INGRESO DE PRECIO DE LISTA', 'INGRESO DE
>   PRECIO ESPECIAL DE LISTA') THEN
>   pasaradinero(movimientostock.datonuevo) WHEN
>   movimientostock.razondemovimiento IN ('ENTRADA DE STOCK', 'SALIDA DE
>   STOCK', 'CAMBIO DE CANTIDAD DE TIPO', 'RESTAURACIÓN DE PRODUCTO',
>   'CAMBIO DE STOCK MINIMO', 'ENTRADA DE BULTO ABIERTO', 'SALIDA DE BULTO
>   ABIERTO', 'SALIDA DE BULTO CERRADO', 'ENTRADA DE BULTO CERRADO') THEN
>   IFNULL(movimientostock.datonuevo,0) ELSE ''  END) AS 'Dato Nuevo',
>   (CASE WHEN movimientostock.razondemovimiento IN ('CAMBIO DE PRODUCTO A
>   VENTA ESPECIAL' ,'CAMBIO DE CODIGO DE BARRAS', 'CAMBIO DE PROVEEDOR',
>   'CAMBIO DE CATEGORÍA', 'CAMBIO DE NOMBRE', 'ALTA DE PRODUCTO', 'BAJA
>   DE PRODUCTO', 'AGREGAR TIPO DE PRODUCTO', 'CAMBIO DE UNIDAD MEDIDA',
>   'CAMBIO DE UNIDAD ABREVIADO', 'CAMBIO DE NOMBRE DE TIPO')  THEN
>   movimientostock.nombreanterior  WHEN movimientostock.razondemovimiento
>   IN ('INGRESO DE PRECIO DE LISTA', 'INGRESO DE PRECIO ESPECIAL DE
>   LISTA', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO FRACCIONARIO', 'CAMBIO
>   DE PRECIO COSTO', 'CAMBIO DE GANANCIA', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO DE LISTA',
>   'CAMBIO DE PRECIO ESPECIAL DE LISTA', 'INGRESO DE PRECIO DE LISTA',
>   'INGRESO DE PRECIO ESPECIAL DE LISTA') THEN
>   pasaradinero(movimientostock.datoanterior) WHEN
>   movimientostock.razondemovimiento IN ('ENTRADA DE STOCK', 'SALIDA DE
>   STOCK', 'CAMBIO DE CANTIDAD DE TIPO', 'RESTAURACIÓN DE PRODUCTO',
>   'CAMBIO DE STOCK MINIMO', 'ENTRADA DE BULTO ABIERTO', 'SALIDA DE BULTO
>   ABIERTO', 'SALIDA DE BULTO CERRADO', 'ENTRADA DE BULTO CERRADO') THEN
>   (IFNULL(movimientostock.datoanterior,0))  ELSE ''  END) AS 'Dato
>   Anterior', (CASE WHEN movimientostock.razondemovimiento IN ('VENTA',
>   'ENTRADA DE STOCK', 'SALIDA DE STOCK', 'ENTRADA DE BULTO CERRADO',
>   'SALIDA DE BULTO CERRADO', 'SALIDA DE BULTO ABIERTO', 'ENTRADA DE
>   BULTO ABIERTO', 'AGREGAR TIPO DE PRODUCTO')  THEN
>   movimientostock.datoextra ELSE ''  END) AS 'Cantidad', (CASE WHEN
>   movimientostock.razondemovimiento IN ('AGREGAR TIPO DE PRODUCTO',
>   'ELIMINA TIPO DE PRODUCTO' , 'CAMBIO DE CANTIDAD DE TIPO', 'CAMBIO DE
>   NOMBRE DE TIPO', 'CAMBIO DE UNIDAD ABREVIADO', 'CAMBIO DE UNIDAD
>   MEDIDA') THEN 1 WHEN movimientostock.razondemovimiento IN ('INGRESO DE
>   PRECIO ESPECIAL DE LISTA', 'INGRESO DE PRECIO DE LISTA', 'CAMBIO DE
>   PRECIO ESPECIAL DE LISTA', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO DE LISTA', 'CAMBIO DE
>   GANANCIA', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO COSTO', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO FRACCIONARIO',
>   'CAMBIO DE PRECIO') THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Tìpo', (IFNULL((SELECT
>   nombre FROM empleados WHERE id = empleado),'')) AS Empleado FROM
>   movimientostock WHERE idproducto = 5100 AND NOT
>   movimientostock.razondemovimiento IN ('AGREGAR TIPO DE PRODUCTO',
>   'ELIMINA TIPO DE PRODUCTO', 'CAMBIO DE CANTIDAD DE TIPO', 'CAMBIO DE
>   NOMBRE DE TIPO', 'CAMBIO DE UNIDAD ABREVIADO', 'CAMBIO DE UNIDAD
>   MEDIDA') order by id;
>
> La consulta tarda 0.037028  tiempo bloqueado Lock_time: 0.000271  Se envian  9 registros y se examinan 33202
>   Explicacion de consulta

```
id  select type         table           type    posible_keys           key      key len fed                                     rows    extra
1   PRIMARY             movimientostock index   razondemovimiento   PRIMARY 4       \N                                      33355   Using where
4   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  empleados       eq_ref  PRIMARY            PRIMARY  4       sistema_tpv.movimientostock.empleado    1   
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  tipodeproducto  eq_ref  PRIMARY,id         PRIMARY  4       sistema_tpv.movimientostock.idproducto  1   
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  productos       eq_ref  PRIMARY,id         PRIMARY  4       sistema_tpv.movimientostock.idproducto  1
```

Comment: por lo que veo, tu problema no es el query, si no el esquema de la base de datos.... si un producto cambio de nombre, todo producto anterior al cambio de nombre, tenia el nombre anterior. En general no se hace asi (y esto es basado en opiniones), si no que se ponen fechas de vigencia a las cosas y punto. o se guarda en una tabla historial, con el mismo formato que la tabla original. Ahora, sobre tu query, decis que tarda, basado en que? si es tan complejo va a tardar.. y el explain plan?

Comment: no te imaginas lo lento una consulta cuando buscas en un varchar mas aun si usas `in` a pesar de que tengas un indice en el campo razondemovimiento

Comment: esta es una base productiva??? si no lo es.. yo pensaria en empezar de vuelta...

Comment: no puedo empezar de nuevo porque ya esta funcionando hoy, tiene ya bases de datos que no puedo borrar

Comment: entonces no lo vas a poder solucionar, el problema no es el query. no entiendo el explain plan ese, pero parece ser que el problema es la busqeuda dentro de los campos de texto. y va a empeorar muchisimo... Esos querys solo se usan para datawarehouse.. si lo estas usando para un sistema productivo.. algo muy malo esta pasando...

Comment: no me dices una solucion! si tienes razon pero no entiendo, jaja, que es datawarehouse? no me dices mucho :S, jacknavarow dice que un varchar es lo que anda lento, que seria necesario para cambiar? si cambio la estructura de la base de datos sin perder los datos, me sirve, la idea es que ande mejor, Hago un query de migracion y listo

Comment: buscalo en tu buscador favorito...y no, no tengo una solucion para esta maraña de datos mezclados!

Comment: Ok, el query está un tanto complejo, pero no has dicho cuan lento es. ¿Cuantos resgistros te devuelve, y cuanto tiempo toma?

Comment: En la pregunta dice La consulta tarda 0.037028 tiempo bloqueado Lock_time: 0.000271 Se envían 9 registros y se examinan 33202, el indice principal es el "Razon de movimiento", y es varchar, a que lo puedo pasar para que sea mas rápido? fulltext? seria una buena solución?

Comment: o sea.. no tarda ni medio segundo.. que es lo que quieres mejorar???

Comment: quiero optimizarla, resulta  que se hace consulta de movimiento de stock seguido, yo no quiero que examine tanto, así tal vez, sea mas rápida.

Comment: Pero como quieres que no examine tanto, si tu query simplemente hace `FROM movimientostock` sin ningún filtro. De ser así, ni modo, tiene que recorrer la tabla entera. A menos que no mostrastes la consulta completa.

Comment: es completa!! completa esta arriba! y una de ejemplo!, donde la ejecuto y funciona, como puedo filtrarla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Los mayores problemas que tiene tu consulta son:

- Busca campos en arrays de cadenas: `campo IN ('texto1','texto2','texto3')`
- Ejecuta 3 `SELECT` anidados por cada registro encontrado: `IFNULL((SELECT tipodeproducto.nombre FROM tipodeproducto WHERE tipodeproducto.id = movimientostock.idproducto),'')`

---

### Para solucionar lo primero

Te recomiendo que normalices el campo `razondemovimiento`, creando una tabla con dos campos y agregando un campo en la tabla `movimientosstock` como FK apuntando a la tabla de razones:

**Creamos la tabla**

```
CREATE TABLE `razones_movimientos`  (
  `cod` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `razon` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cod`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;
```

**Llenamos la tabla con los valores usados en tu consulta**

```
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (0, 'AGREGAR TIPO DE PRODUCTO');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (1, 'ALTA DE PRODUCTO');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (2, 'BAJA DE PRODUCTO');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (3, 'CAMBIO DE CANTIDAD DE TIPO');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (4, 'CAMBIO DE CATEGORÍA');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (5, 'CAMBIO DE CODIGO DE BARRAS');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (6, 'CAMBIO DE GANANCIA');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (7, 'CAMBIO DE NOMBRE DE TIPO');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (8, 'CAMBIO DE NOMBRE');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (9, 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO COSTO');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (10, 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO DE LISTA');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (11, 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO ESPECIAL DE LISTA');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (12, 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO FRACCIONARIO');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (13, 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (14, 'CAMBIO DE PRODUCTO A VENTA ESPECIAL');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (15, 'CAMBIO DE PRODUCTO A VENTA FRACCIONARIA');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (16, 'CAMBIO DE PROVEEDOR');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (17, 'CAMBIO DE STOCK MINIMO');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (18, 'CAMBIO DE TIPO DE PRODUCTO');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (19, 'CAMBIO DE UNIDAD ABREVIADO');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (20, 'CAMBIO DE UNIDAD MEDIDA');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (21, 'ELIMINA TIPO DE PRODUCTO');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (22, 'ENTRADA DE BULTO ABIERTO');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (23, 'ENTRADA DE BULTO CERRADO');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (24, 'ENTRADA DE STOCK');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (25, 'INGRESO DE PRECIO DE LISTA');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (26, 'INGRESO DE PRECIO ESPECIAL DE LISTA');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (27, 'RESTAURACIÓN DE PRODUCTO');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (28, 'SALIDA DE BULTO ABIERTO');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (29, 'SALIDA DE BULTO CERRADO');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (30, 'SALIDA DE STOCK');
INSERT INTO `razones_movimientos` VALUES (31, 'VENTA');
```

**Agregamos el campo que va a ser FK en tu tabla (pero todavía no lo definimos como FK, porque los valores están mal)**

```
ALTER TABLE movimientostock 
ADD COLUMN cod_razondemovimiento int(11) AFTER idproducto;
```

**Ahora podemos poner los valores correctos en tu tabla**

```
UPDATE movimientostock
LEFT JOIN razones_movimientos ON movimientostock.razondemovimiento = razones_movimientos.razon
SET movimientostock.cod_razondemovimiento=razones_movimientos.cod;
```

**Y definir el campo que agregamos, ahora sí, como FK**

```
ALTER TABLE movimientostock
ADD FOREIGN KEY (cod_razondemovimiento) REFERENCES razones_movimientos (cod)
ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

---

### Para solucionar lo segundo

En lugar de anidar un `SELECT` dentro de los `IFNULL`, podrías hacer 3 `LEFT JOIN` y, en los `IFNULL`, evaluar el campo de texto obtenido por el `LEFT JOIN`.

Así, reemplazarías

```
IFNULL((SELECT tipodeproducto.nombre FROM tipodeproducto WHERE tipodeproducto.id = movimientostock.idproducto),'')
```

por las dos siguientes

```
IFNULL(tipodeproducto.nombre, '' )
(...) LEFT JOIN tipodeproducto ON movimientostock.idproducto = tipodeproducto.id
```

---

### COMO QUEDARIA AL FINAL

```
SELECT
    movimientostock.id AS Id,
    movimientostock.fechademovimiento AS 'Fecha de Movimiento',
    (
    CASE
        WHEN movimientostock.cod_razondemovimiento IN ( 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31 )
            THEN IFNULL(productos.nombre, '' ) 
        WHEN movimientostock.cod_razondemovimiento IN ( 0, 3, 7, 19, 20, 21 )
            THEN IFNULL(tipodeproducto.nombre, '' )
        ELSE ''
    END
    ) AS 'Nombre',
    movimientostock.cod_razondemovimiento AS 'Tipo de Movimiento',
    (
    CASE
        WHEN movimientostock.cod_razondemovimiento IN ( 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 14, 16, 19, 20 )
            THEN movimientostock.nombrenuevo
        WHEN movimientostock.cod_razondemovimiento IN ( 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 25, 25, 26 )
            THEN pasaradinero( movimientostock.datonuevo )
        WHEN movimientostock.cod_razondemovimiento IN ( 3, 17, 22, 23, 24, 27, 28, 29, 30 )
            THEN IFNULL( movimientostock.datonuevo, 0 )
        ELSE '' 
    END 
    ) AS 'Dato Nuevo',
    (
    CASE
        WHEN movimientostock.cod_razondemovimiento IN ( 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 14, 16, 19, 20 )
            THEN movimientostock.nombreanterior 
        WHEN movimientostock.cod_razondemovimiento IN ( 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 25, 26 )
            THEN pasaradinero( movimientostock.datoanterior ) 
        WHEN movimientostock.cod_razondemovimiento IN ( 3, 17, 22, 23, 24, 27, 28, 29, 30 )
            THEN IFNULL( movimientostock.datoanterior, 0 )
        ELSE '' 
    END 
    ) AS 'Dato Anterior',
    (
    CASE
        WHEN movimientostock.cod_razondemovimiento IN ( 0, 22, 23, 24, 28, 29, 30, 31 )
            THEN movimientostock.datoextra
        ELSE '' 
    END 
    ) AS 'Cantidad',
    (
    CASE
        WHEN movimientostock.cod_razondemovimiento IN ( 0, 3, 7, 19, 20, 21 )
            THEN 1 
        WHEN movimientostock.cod_razondemovimiento IN ( 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 25, 26 )
            THEN 2
        ELSE 0 
    END 
    ) AS 'Tipo',
    IFNULL(empleado.nombre, '' ) AS 'Empleado'
FROM
    movimientostock
LEFT JOIN empleados ON movimientostock.empleado = empleados.id
LEFT JOIN tipodeproducto ON movimientostock.idproducto = tipodeproducto.id
LEFT JOIN productos ON movimientostock.idproducto = productos.id;
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda, y no dudes en pedirme cualquier aclaración.

Es una pregunta de hace casi 2 años, pero el hecho de que siguiera sin ser respondida y siguiera recibiendo visitas habla de que ésto le interesa a algunos más.

Answer (score -2):

en ese caso es mejor hacerlo como procedimiento almacenado para ir validando los datos o validar los datos en tu codigo, porque claramente la perfomance de tu consulta si bien puede que "funcione" no es la mejor te recomiendo realizar un procedimiento almacenado te dare un pequeño ejemplo:

`@razondemovimiento varchar(50)
  set @razondemovimiento = 'select razondemovimiento  from stockmovimiento' 
  if (@razondemovimiento in ('CAMBIO DE PRODUCTO A VENTA FRACCIONARIA', 'VENTA', 'CAMBIO DE CODIGO DE BARRAS', 'CAMBIO DE PROVEEDOR', 'CAMBIO DE CATEGORÍA', 'CAMBIO DE NOMBRE', 'ENTRADA DE STOCK', 'SALIDA DE STOCK', 'CAMBIO DE TIPO DE PRODUCTO', 'ENTRADA DE BULTO CERRADO', 'SALIDA DE BULTO CERRADO', 'SALIDA DE BULTO ABIERTO', 'ENTRADA DE BULTO ABIERTO', 'CAMBIO DE STOCK MINIMO', 'BAJA DE PRODUCTO', 'RESTAURACIÓN DE PRODUCTO', 'BAJA DE PRODUCTO', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO FRACCIONARIO', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO COSTO', 'CAMBIO DE GANANCIA', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO DE LISTA', 'CAMBIO DE PRECIO ESPECIAL DE LISTA', 'INGRESO DE PRECIO DE LISTA', 'INGRESO DE PRECIO ESPECIAL DE LISTA') )`{

```
aca tu select}
else{}
```

o derechamente realizar inner join pero te recomiendo eso a utilizar la query que indicas porque de verdad estas sobrecargando el servidor de una manera cabrona ademas de ser una mala practica

Comment: que servidor estaria sobrecargando? podrias explicar un poco mas el concepto? porque al final via SP o query directo, la query se termina ejecutando en la base de datos.